# how to determine the inside and the outside of a shape in a grayscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of ground like this:

[image: input]

and I also have array of points that surrounded the shape as you can see on the picture.

my goal is to display the normal vector for each point in a way that it points to the "inside" area, i.e. to the  more white area.
My try was to calculate the normal vector for each point (the 2 directions of it).
After I got the 2 sided normal vector I tried to determine which side points to the "inside" by summing up an area (3*3, 5*5...) around the 2 edges of the normal and compare between them ().
the results were ambiguous..

I need help to find another idea..

Answer (score 1):

While I am expecting someone to come with a smarter mathematical solution, I'll give you a programmatic/MATLAB solution for this. Note that a nice/easy solution can be found if the area is convex, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

[Use `inpolygon`!](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html?refresh=true)

You mention that you have the points and normal vectors (else getting normals is pretty easy). Add to the points in the boundary a very small amount in the normal distance, thus computing new points that will be

a) Inside the area

b) outside the area

depending on which direction the normal is pointing to.

Define a polygon with the original points and then test `inpolygon` the new points with the old points. For the points that are in, the normal was inwards, while if they are out, the normal was outwards.

This has a flaw when the polygon is very non-convex, as sometimes something pointing out can make the point in. However, if you have calculated all the normals using adjacent points, they will be either all outwards or all inwards. you can know why by doing the `inpolygon` trick and then using the most repeated direction.

Comment: If you manage to have the difference between true points and temporary ones in order of `realmin`, then the shape "disturbance" must be below the resolution to screw the results. You can also test displacement in both directions and check for `true-true` or `false-false` results.

Answer (score 1):

You can also benefit from the features of vector multiplications.

- For scalar multiplication

  - `A . B > 0` when angle between vectros is lower than 90°;
  - `A . B < 0` when angle is greater than 90°;
  - `A . B = 0` when angle is equal to 90°.
- For vector multiplication

  - `A x B` points upwards when vector order is "right-hand";
  - `A x B` points downwards vhen vectro order is "left-hand";
  - `A x B` is `(0,0,0)` when vectors are collinear.

Then write your code as folloows:

1. Calculate normal and tangential vector (`n{ii}`, `t{ii}`) for every point.
2. Calculate `v{ii} = n{ii} x t{ii}` for every point.
3. Calculate `sg(ii)=sign(v{ii-1}.v{ii})` for every point.

`sg(ii)` is positive when `ii`-th vector have same direction as the `ii-1`th one.
`sg(ii)` is negative when `ii`-th vector points inwards and `ii-1`th points outwards or vice versa.

If you determine for any point whether the normal vector points iwards or outwards you can then easily decide the direction of all points.

Comment: thanks. 2 things: Can you please tell me what `sg(...)` represents? Another thing: I am not sure if what you wrote helps to  determines the "inside" and "outside" or helps to make a conclusion after determine for any point whether the normal vector points inwards or outwards. Thanks again!

Comment: 1. I'm sorry I misspelled `sign` function. It checks whether the product of `v{ii}` and `v{ii-1}` is positive or negative. You can also compare it with zero. 2. If you determine one vector to be insider or outsider, for example by Ander's answer, you can assess all vectors without any flaw.

Comment: If you **know** that you are checking the points clockwise, or counter-clockwise, you have enough information as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the points are not arranged clockwise or counter-clockwise.